# Traceback counts line "wrong" IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, ansys

I've a problem with IronPython in Ansys 2021 R2 with SpaceClaim.
The problem is, when I throw an exception, traceback counts the "wrong" line number. I run this code in the Script Editor from SpaceClaim.
Example:

```
1: import sys
2: import traceback
3: 
4: a = 10 
5: try:
6:    b = a / 0
7: except Exception as e:
8:    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
9:    print("lineno: " + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno))
```

Output is:
lineno: 2
But it shoud be:
lineno: 6. How can I get the right line number?

Comment: Is there a question?  Why tag this "ansys" - nothing pertains to that? Maybe file a bug for ironpython?`

Comment: Are you running this interactively? It kind of sounds like you're running this interactively. If not, how are you running this?

Comment: I think user2357112 is correct here. When you start SpaceClaim the IronPython script engine is also started. All definitions persist whiting that SpaceClaim sessions so that would suggest that it is a single interactive IronPython session, that the scripts are ran in.

Comment: @user2357112 I run the Script in the Script Editor, so I guess I run it interacively but not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't know enough about the SpaceClaim Script Editor to be fully sure of what's going on. It could be running the code in smaller chunks than a whole script, with the try-except as one chunk and `b = a / 0` as the second line of that chunk. It could also be running different code than what you see (and the "Smart Variables" feature seems fairly likely to involve doing that, though it could work other ways).

Comment: @user2357112 As far as I understand, the script is executed in smaller chunks, with the try-except as one chunk.